# AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'

Tags: python

I tried below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\chrome.chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Error I got:

```
C:\Users\utkarsh\PycharmProjects\SeleniumScripts\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/utkarsh/PycharmProjects/SeleniumScripts/selenium examples/prog1.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/utkarsh/PycharmProjects/SeleniumScripts/selenium examples/prog1.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\chrome.chromedriver.exe")
    AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Need help to get started with selenium, please help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a script called `selenium.py`. Rename that and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

please reconfirm you have done following steps:

1. Download selenium by using `pip install -U selenium` command
2. Download the `chromedriver.exe`, and put it's path into system variable (In order to confirm if you have put correct path, start command prompt and insert `chromedriver`, if succeed, your chrome version should be displayed)
3. When you installed python, in `python\Lib\site-packages` folder there is a built-in selenium package, by that saying, when you put `from selenium import webdriver` this will import `webdriver` from the built-in selenium package but not the one you just installed in step1, in order for python to import from your newly installed `selenium package` (because this package contains stuffs we need), you can simply replace `python\Lib\site-packages\selenium` by your newly installed selenium folder.